# Getting the key binding for the current command

Tags: key-bindings, commands

`this-command-keys` and `this-command-keys-vector` return the entire key sequence that fired the current command.  However, such sequence will contain any prefix argument, too.  Is there a function or variable - let's call it `this-command-key-binding` - to get just the key sequence for the command, without any prefix, so that `(key-binding (this-command-binding))` returns the same value as `this-command`, even in the presence of a prefix argument?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're looking for `this-single-command-keys`.